# Inner join removes some rows unnecessarily

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables defined like so

```
CREATE TABLE participants(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT NOT NULL,
    Title TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE meetings (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Subject TEXT NOT NULL,
    Organizer TEXT NOT NULL,
    StartTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    EndTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE meetings_participants(
    meeting_id int not null,
    participant_id int not null,
    primary key (meeting_id, participant_id),
    foreign key(meeting_id) references meetings(id),
    foreign key(participant_id) references participants(id)
);
```

I want to find meetings happening today with participants in them.
When I run this query I basically get them

```
SELECT * from meetings 
INNER JOIN meetings_participants ON meetings.id = meetings_participants.meeting_id 
INNER JOIN participants ON meetings_participants.participant_id = participants.id 
WHERE starttime::date = NOW()::date;
```

Problem is this query discards meetings where there are no participants yet, I still wish to include them into my query result. How can I modify my query to work like that ?

Comment: You probably want a `left join` but then you'd need to move the condition on starttime to the JOIN condition, not to the WHERE clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, why would he move the where condition to join? starttime is a column in meetings.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: ah, right. I overlooked that. In that case it can stay in the WHERE clause

Comment: @Jeekim please tell what you actually want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER. Using ::date casting you are implying that you are only interested them to be taking place today, whether or not it might already ended. Still you should include EndTime in your query, taking into consideration that there might be meetings that span over several days:

```
SELECT * from meetings 
left join meetings_participants on meetings.id = meetings_participants.meeting_id 
left join participants on meetings_participants.participant_id = participants.id 
WHERE starttime::date <= NOW()::date and endtime::date >= NOW()::date ;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ffab06b88261b790a50e0f039119e7c3) here.

EDIT: Participants' name and title as JSON array:

```
SELECT id, subject, organizer, starttime, endtime, jsonb_pretty(tmp.participants)
from meetings m
         left join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg(row_to_json(tp)) as participants
    from (select p.name, p.title
          from meetings_participants mp
                   inner join participants p on mp.participant_id = p.id
          where mp.meeting_id = m.id
         ) tp
    ) tmp on true
WHERE starttime::date <= NOW()::date
  and endtime::date >= NOW()::date;
```

[DBFiddle demo for participants added as JSON](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1677d7f404a50bfd737c6a60d8dfba20)

Comment: `NOW()::date` can also be written as `current_date`

Comment: But questioner retrieves only those rows which starttime is today.. not end time

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, exactly. I copy pasted :)

Comment: @RahulBiswas, I meant a meeting might have started on Jan 31st and ends today or tomorrow. To catch it in the results, we need endtime check. You can see in DBFiddle demo.

Comment: Meetings are one day only, so for date either time check works. Salman offered an extra option with aggregate to get participant list per event whic is best

Comment: @Jeekim, you didn't say you wanted just names of participants as a single value or I missed that. Extending on it, one could say getting participant data as JSON is much better.

Comment: @Cetin Basos Yeah I didnt know I wanted that until it was said. Could you update your answer to provide participant info both name and title as Json attached to event ? so there is a list of participants attached to each event

Comment: @Jeekim, updated to include participants' name, title as json. BTW, jsonb_pretty() is just for making it pretty display wise.

Comment: perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention whether you want each participant on a separate row or as an aggregate (e.g. a comma separated list). If former then change inner to left join. For the latter case you could:

```
SELECT meetings.*, (
    SELECT string_agg(participants.name, ', ')
    FROM meetings_participants
    JOIN participants ON meetings_participants.participant_id = participants.id
    WHERE meetings_participants.meeting_id = meetings.id
) AS participants_list
FROM meetings 
WHERE starttime::date = current_date
```

Comment: Yes ! Participant list per meeting is best!

Comment: how would I add to string_agg to include also participant title ?